# Mi script para hacer backups me da un error : 'Rechazo cobarde'

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Aqui el script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source '/home/jose/Documentos/scripts/colors.sh'


directorio=$1
lugarCopia=$2
fecha=$(date +%Y_%m_%d)

#Helper !
if [[ $1 == '--help' ]]; then
    echo "1º Parametro: Directorio del cual se quiere hacer un backup."
    echo "2º Parametro: Directorio donde almacenar el backup."
    exit 1
fi

#Comprobaciones params obligatorios
if [[ -z $directorio ]]; then
    echo -e "$RED ERR!: ${ENDCOLOR} Debes indicar un directorio para hacer backup."
    exit 1
elif [[ -z $lugarCopia ]]; then
    echo -e "$RED ERR!: $ENDCOLOR Debes indicar donde guardar el backup."
    exit 1
fi

#Compruebo si los params son "." para poner el currentdir
if [[ $directorio == "." ]]; then
    directorio=$(pwd)
fi
if [[ $lugarCopia == "." ]]; then
    lugarCopia=$(pwd)
fi

nombreBackUp=$(basename $directorio)
outputName="$lugarCopia/$nombreBackUp.tar.gz"

echo "Se va a hacer un backup del directorio '$directorio' en '$lugarCopia' con el nombre '$nombreBackUp'"
 
echo "tar cvfz $lugarCopia/$nombreBackUp.tar.gz $directorio"
tar cvfz "$outputName $directorio" 

if [[ -f $outputName ]]; then
    echo -e "$GREEN Backup Finalizado !!"
    exit 1
else    
    echo -e "$RED Ha ocurrido un error al hacer el backup"
    exit 1
fi
```

## Output:

```
tar: Rechazo cobarde a crear un archivo vacío
Pruebe 'tar --help' o 'tar --usage' para más información.
```

No es un fichero vacio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy muy seguro, pero intenta 1) Cambiando el orden de los parámetros, y 2) Poniendo por separado tanto lo que se va a comprimir, como el archivo destino:

Cambia de esto:

```
tar cvfz "$outputName $directorio"
```

A esto:

```
tar cvzf "$outputName" "$directorio"
```

Pensaría que eso funcionaría porque con el parámetro `f`, lo que esté a la derecha tendría que ser el nombre de archivo comprimido.

Comment: exacto. El problema está en que `tar` no recibe el parámetro del fichero destino, sino que solo interpreta el del directorio de donde coger los datos. En inglés dice [tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive](https://askubuntu.com/a/880114/143251)